# Does using event.preventDefault() in "mousedown" prevent "click" or "mouseup" event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, preventdefault

I am new to `jquery` and i have a doubt whether using `events.preventDefault()` in the `mousedown` or `mouseup` events does prevent the `click` or `dblclick` event?

Please provide me a clarification or a sample.

Thanks in advance.
Madhu

Comment: events.preventDefault() only prevent the default action of event.

Comment: After the reading the other Felix' answer, I think I understand your question now. You should adjust the title though, because it is misleading.

Comment: Thank you I got what i want. StackOverFlow Rockzzzzzzzzzzzz....

Comment: @Madhu, could you please give the example of how did you get this.

Comment: @SonuK, the comment stackoverflow.com/questions/21900470#comment-33167721 clarified me and in my case a new element is inserted when `mousedown` and hence the target changed and subsequent `click` get prevented. I do some design changes to resolve this.

Comment: It does prevent onchange from fireing if you use it in onmousedown

Answer (score 12):

Neither of `mouseup` or `mousedown` prevent the default click event.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n45k9/)

You need to use `click()`:

```js
$('#test').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="alert('Clicked')" id="test">Click Here</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n45k9/1/)

Comment: I know that buddy, but i want to know whether it will prevent the sub-sequent events from happening?

Comment: No, it's not. e.preventDefault() just prevent the default action of your element not subsequent elements or other events

Answer (score 3):

It does not prevent the event itself, but the **action** that is **triggered** by the event.

A simple example would be clicking on an anchor link. The default action of the click event is to take the browser to a new URL. In this case, it won't happen.

Comment: Thanks.I thought it prevents the sub-sequent events from happening. Does it prevent them?

Comment: It does not. If you want to prevent subsequent events you'd need to use either `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: @Quinn Doesn't prevent further events for me. I wouldn't have thought so either, since what should propagation have to do with it?