# How can I check the checkbox with mousedown event?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have the following code:

```js
checkbox.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
        if (!this.checked) {
            this.checked = true;
        }
    });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
```

It should turn on the checkbox when mouse button is down.
And it works perfectly but when I release the button, the checkbox turns back off. How can i fix this?

Comment: It remains checked, if `mouseup` is not on the checkbox (which then would trigger a click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
checkbox.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    if(!this.checked) {
        var preventUnselect = function(){
            this.checked = true;            
            checkbox.removeEventListener('click', preventUnselect)
        };
        checkbox.addEventListener('click', preventUnselect)
        this.checked = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
```

I'm pretty sure that your checkbox gets unchecked because default behavior of checkbox is to change it's state after click. If you check checkbox after mousedown, then it's state get switched(turned back to unchecked) after click event completes. Just click the checkbox and move the pointer outside of it while still holding left mouse key down - checkbox won't get unchecked when you release the button..

You have to bind click event after mousedown, and remove that event afterward. If event wasn't removed your checkbox would be checked forever.

Comment: That helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
checkbox.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){
    this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that checkboxes already have this behaviour as a default built into it by the browsers. I you want to see if a checkbox is checked or not you can simply look at the `checked` property of the DOM element. For example:

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById('Mycheckbox');

// this onclick now purely for demonstration purposes
checkbox.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log(checkbox.checked);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="Mycheckbox"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As  explained in
[Does using event.preventDefault() in "mousedown" prevent "click" or "mouseup" event in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21900470/does-using-event-preventdefault-in-mousedown-prevent-click-or-mouseup-ev)
one can `preventDefault` of the `click` event, which follows after `mousedown`

```js
checkbox.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    if (!this.checked)
        this.checked = true;
})

checkbox.addEventListener('click', e => e.preventDefault())
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
```